# Proper way to make this a shell script

Tags: linux, centos

Hi guys anyone can guide me or re-write my script? well i manually type this code everytime i reinstall.
i want to make this all in just 1 script file only

```
    yum update -y
    yum install httpd -y
    service httpd start
    yum install mysql-server -y && service mysqld start && mysql_secure_installation
    yum install php php-mysql -y && service httpd restart
    rpm -ivh https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm && yum check-update && yum install phpMyAdmin -y

   vi /etc/httpd/conf.d/phpMyAdmin.conf (Will edit some of line)
yum install git -y && yum install gcc make mysql mysql-devel mysql-server pcre-devel zlib-devel && yum -y install dos2unix gdb nano screen unzip wget zip
yum -y groupinstall Desktop && yum -y install tigervnc-server pixman pixman-devel libXfont
vncpasswd
vi /etc/sysconfig/vncservers
(Will write this on the bottom of vncservers)
VNCSERVERS="1:root"
VNCSERVERARGS[1]="-geometry 1100x768"

yum -y install xterm && yum -y install subversion && yum install gnome-utils -y && yum -y install nautilus-open-terminal
service vncserver start
chkconfig httpd on && chkconfig mysqld on && chkconfig vncserver on

reboot
```

=====
Is there anyone can help me to clean up and put that in 1 file only?

Comment: Put it in a file. Make it executable. Run it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in some directory of your choice do `touch [script_name].sh` then enter the following into the script

```
#!/bin/bash
#if not sudo or root yum fails
if [ "$EUID" -ne 0 ]
  then echo "Please run as root"
  exit
fi

yum update -y
yum install httpd -y
service httpd start
yum install mysql-server -y && service mysqld start && mysql_secure_installation
yum install php php-mysql -y && service httpd restart
rpm -ivh https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm && yum check-update && yum install phpMyAdmin -y

sed -i '24s/Deny from All/Allow from All/' /etc/httpd/conf.d/phpMyAdmin.conf
yum install git -y && yum install gcc make mysql mysql-devel mysql-server pcre-devel zlib-devel && yum -y install dos2unix gdb nano screen unzip wget zip
yum -y groupinstall Desktop && yum -y install tigervnc-server pixman pixman-devel libXfont
vncpasswd
echo VNCSERVERS="1:root" >> /etc/sysconfig/vncservers
echo VNCSERVERARGS[1]="-geometry 1100x768" >> /etc/sysconfig/vncservers

yum -y install xterm && yum -y install subversion && yum install gnome-utils -y && yum -y install nautilus-open-terminal
service vncserver start
chkconfig httpd on && chkconfig mysqld on && chkconfig vncserver on
echo rebooting computer
sleep 5
reboot
```

After that is done exit the text editor and run the command `chmod +x /scriptpath/[script_name].sh` and then `cd` to the directory containing the script and run `./[script_name].sh`.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for replying. in /etc/httpd/conf.d/phpMyAdmin.conf i was going to edit the line 24 which is "Deny from All" to "Allow from All"   what code should i put in the script?

Comment: @Ranz edited so that it goes to line 24 and replaces inline Deny from All with Allow from All